# Computing singularities of a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, complex-geometry, singularity

Let $Y$ be the abelian variety $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i] \times \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i] $.  Let $X$ be the quotient of $Y$ by action of the group generated by the map $\eta(x,y)=(ix,iy)$. This group generated is of order 4, and is given by $\{e, -e, \eta, -\eta\}$ where $e$ is the identity map.

How can we show that $X$ is in fact a rational surface and has 10 singularities? I do know we have to look at the fixed points by the subgroups generated by $\eta$ but I have very little idea on how to proceed. Any hints given or links to papers describing this particular construction would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have been told that I need to look at the fixed points of the orbit, which in this case is simply the 0 class. How can I proceed?

Comment: From where do you know that  $X$ has 10 singularities? I could find only $9$ special orbits in $Y$.

Comment: From the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0895 "Normal subgroups in the Cremona group". They claimed that $X$ has 10 singularities, all of which can be resolved within a single blowup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call $E=\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Then $Y= E\times E$ and $X=Y/\eta$. The singularities of $X$ come from orbits on $Y$ with nontrivial stabilizer.

Since $\eta$ has order four, a possible stabilizer is generated either by $\eta$ or $\eta^2$. Hence we first look for the points fixed by $\eta^2(x,y) = (-x,-y)$. Moreove the action is diagonal and we may analyse each factor.

Imposing that $-(a+bi) \equiv a+bi \mod{\mathbb{Z}[i]}$ it follows that $$a+bi \mod{\mathbb{Z}[i]}\in \left\{0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{i}{2}, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \right\} = K\subset E $$
Then the points with nontrivial stabilizer by $\eta$ are in $K\times K$. This gives us ten orbits
$$
\left\{\left(0,0\right)\right\},
 \left\{\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right),\left(0,\frac{i}{2}\right)\right\}, 
\left\{\left(0,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right\},  
\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right),\left(\frac{i}{2},0\right)\right\}, 
\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right),\left(\frac{i}{2},\frac{i}{2}\right)\right\}, 
\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{i}{2}\right),\left(\frac{i}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}, 
\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right),\left(\frac{i}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right\}, 
\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2},0\right)\right\}, 
\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right),\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2},\frac{i}{2}\right)\right\}, 
\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right\}.
$$

We may use Castelnuovo's criterion to determine the rationality. First, if $S$ is a a smooth surface obtained from $X$ by resolution of singularities, then from $Y= E\times E$ we have -- by [Proposition 2.2 here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01759382) --
$$
q(S) = g(E/\eta|_E) + g(E/\eta|_E) = 0.
$$
and using a [Kunneth type formula for coherent sheaves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34673/kunneth-formula-for-sheaf-cohomology-of-varieties) we have
$$
P_2 = h^0(S,K_S^{\otimes 2}) = h^0(E\times E, K_E^{\otimes 2}  \boxtimes K_E^{\otimes 2} )^\eta = h^0(E, K_E^{\otimes 2})^{\eta|_E}\cdot h^0(E, K_E^{\otimes 2})^{\eta|_E} = 0.
$$

Therefore $P_2 = q =0$ and $S$ (hence $X$) is rational by Castelnuovo's rationality criterion.

Besides Serrano's paper I'd recomend [Harris, Algebraic Geometry](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387977164) and [Barth et ali, Compact Complex Surfaces](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540008323).

Let me know if there is any point that is not clear.

Comment: Hi Alan. Thank you so much for the amazing and detailed answer. May I also ask the following: the paper claims that every automorphism on $X$ can be lifted to that on $Y$. Why is this true? I know it is not true that you can lift an autmorphism on a rational map to that on an abelian variety in general.

Comment: I could not understand their argument but I believe it has something to do with the Galois Theory of the covering $Y \to X$.